# Why my Shell sorting is so slow

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement shell sorting algorithm myself. I wrote my own code and didn't watch to any code samples only watch [the video of algorithm description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzXAVXddcPU)

My sort works but very slow (bubble sort 100 items - 0.007 s; shell sort 100 items - 4.83 s), how is it possible to improve it?

```
void print(vector<float>vec)
{
    for (float i : vec)
    cout << i << " ";
    cout << "\n\n";
}

void Shell_sorting(vector<float>&values)
{
    int swapping = 0;
    int step = values.size();
    clock_t start;
    double duration;
    start = clock();

    while (step/2 >= 1)
    {
        step /= 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size()-step; i++)
        {
            if ((i + step < values.size()))
            {
                if ((values[i + step] < values[i]))
                {
                    swap(values[i], values[i + step]);
                    print(values);
                    ++swapping;
                    int c = i;
                    while (c - step > 0)
                    {
                        if (values[c] < values[c - step])
                        {
                            swap(values[c], values[c - step]);
                            print(values);
                            ++swapping;
                            c -= step;
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    duration = (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    print(values);
    cout << swapping << "  " << duration;
    print(values);
}
```

Comment: If you want to improve working code better ask your question at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `if ((i + step < values.size()))` isn't this always true (it's the condition in the for loop).

Comment: @manni66, if i > value.size()-step it is false

Comment: But `i < values.size()-step` is allways true.

Comment: @manni66,you are right previously  i changed  for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) for for (int i = 0; i < values.size()-step; i++) so i said it but what do you think about speed of working maybe in code are unneseccary operations?

Comment: I think a bottleneck in your code could be the print function. Printing something on the stdout is an expansive activity. Try to remove it. Besides, the use of function print() takes extra time since you need to copy the values's value into the function local parameter, give the control to the function and at the end of its executing, return the control to the main.

Comment: @markblacksmith I don't know, but you implemented the original shell sort that has a complexity of O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {
                            726,621,81,719,167,958,607,130,263,108,
                            134,235,508,407,153,162,849,923,996,975,
                            250,78,460,667,654,62,865,973,477,912,
                            580,996,156,615,542,655,240,847,613,497,
                            274,241,398,84,436,803,138,677,470,606,
                            226,593,620,396,460,448,198,958,566,599,
                            762,248,461,191,933,805,288,185,21,340,
                            458,592,703,303,509,55,190,318,310,189,
                            780,923,933,546,816,627,47,377,253,709,
                            992,421,587,768,908,261,946,75,682,948,
                            };

    std::vector<int> gaps = {5, 2, 1};
    int j;

    for (int gap : gaps) {
        for (int i = gap; i < vec.size(); i++) 
        {
            j = i-gap;
            while (j >= 0) {
                if (vec[j+gap] < vec[j])
                {
                    int temp = vec[j+gap];
                    vec[j+gap] = vec[j];
                    vec[j] = temp;
                    j = j-gap;
                }
                else break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int item : vec) std::cout << item << " " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I prefer to use a vector to store gap data so that you do not need to compute the division (which is an expansive operation). Besides, this choice, gives your code more flexibility.

the extern loop cycles on gap values. Once choosen the gap, you iterate over your vector, starting from `vec[gap]` and explore if there are elements smaller then it according to the logic of the Shell Sort.

So, you start setting `j=i-gap` and test the if condition. If it is true, swap items and then repeat the while loop decrementing `j`. **Note**: `vec[j+gap]`is the element that in the last loop cycle was swapped. If the condition is true, there's no reason to continue in the loop, so you can exit from it with a `break`.

On my machine, it took 0.002s calculated using the `time` shell command (the time includes the process of printing numbers).

p.s. to generate all that numbers and write them in the array, since i'm too lazy to write a random function, i used [this link](https://www.random.org/integers/?mode=advanced) and then i edited the output in the shell with:

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/,/g' num | sed -e 's/$/,/'
```